# MVC Routing in .NET Core React project isn't picking up my Controller

Tags: c#, reactjs, model-view-controller, routes

I am learning how to create React applications with ASP.NET Core. As a newbie I am starting at the very beginning and trying to get "Hello World" displayed on the home page. I have used Visual Studio's default React.js project template to get me started. The routes are set to default. Here are my files:

Home.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { message: "" };

        fetch('api/Home/Message')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
          this.setState({ message: data });
        });

    }

  render () {
      return (

            <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>

    );
  }
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace TestingReactDotNet.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]   
public class HomeController :  Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Message()
        {
            var response = "Hello World";
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the HTTP response that is being parsed to Json isn't the correct one. I have console.logged it out in order to try to debug, and it appears that `response.json())` is retrieving all of the text in the default `public/index.html` file that comes with the template application. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Apologies if I am missing something super obvious - I use a Mac, so the file structure and Visual Studio IDE are quite different and I have struggled to understand quite a few of the tutorials/answers already out there.

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I am getting the same issue while hitting the controller method. I am getting "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." which is default message of index.html in react app @juemura7

Comment: Hi @DevProf - for my example I replaced `public async Task<string> Message()` with `public string Message()`

Answer (score 1):

To hit your `Message()` function you must make a HttpGet to `'api/Home'` not `'api/Home/Message'`.

If you want your endpoint to be `'api/Home/Message'` then you must specify the route for the `Message()` function like so:

```
// api/Home/Message
[HttpGet, Route("Message")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Message()
```

Comment: Thank you but this still doesn't work and is returning index.html :(

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding a context line in `setupProxy.js`
You can locate it at

> ClientApp -> src -> setupProxy.js

You must add the name of controller you want to use in the array context list.

Answer (score 0):

Class `Controller` is for MVC which does generate full web pages.

For Web API you need to extend `ControllerBase`. And you should just return your value/object straight:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController :  ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet, Route("message")]
    public async Task<string> Message()
    {
        var response = "Hello World";
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MichaelDomashchenko - appreciate your help. Unfortunately the same error occurred however :(

Comment: You still get back the whole index.html from the server? You should be getting your message straight now. The problem might be that a single string is not quite json. Put a breakpoint in Chrome on `.then(response` line. What's in response?

Comment: Hi @MichaelDomashchenko - yes, it still returns the whole index.html instead of the message. `.then(response)` returns this error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` and the index.html code: `<!DOCTYPE html>...`

Comment: @jordantomiko, @Noremac was correct, for API controllers you need to explicitly specify the `message` segment with method-level `Route` attribute. Try adding `[ApiController]` to your class, though for me it worked both ways. Also, try enabling "Debug" level for all logging, including System and Microsoft, in your appsettings.Development.json file, that might provide additional clues.